# More complex inheritance in YAML?

Tags: inheritance, yaml

YAML has inheritance. The most clear example I have ever seen is here: [http://blog.101ideas.cz/posts/dry-your-yaml-files.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20130213112648/http://blog.101ideas.cz/posts/dry-your-yaml-files.html)

I need something more complex: I need to override object's object's property. Here is an example:

```
database: &default
  server:
    ip: 192.168.1.5
    port: 2000
  db_name: test
  user: 
    name: root
    password: root

# database foo differs from default by only its port and user password
foo_database:
  <<: *default
  server:
    port: 2001
  db_name: foo
  user:
    password: foo_root
```

I want to get this result:

```
foo_database.server.ip -> 192.168.1.5
foo_database.server.port -> 2001
foo_database.db_name -> foo
foo_database.user.name -> root
foo_database.user.password -> foo_root
```

But if you declare like this, you will get these properties incorrect (according to expected values):

```
foo_database.server.ip -> will be None
foo_database.user.name -> will be None
```

because new "server" object has only "port" property and it overrides whole old "server" object.

How do I get the kind of inheritance which I want to achieve?

## Edit

[Here is](https://gist.github.com/ceremcem/4ca8d774e660c579682839620d8c2da8) my exact intention with a working code in [LiveScript](http://livescript.net/):

```
config = 
  default: 
    ip: \192.168.1.5
    port: 2000
    name: \root 
    password: \root 
    db:
      name: \default
      location: \LA

  foo-database:~ -> @default `merge` do 
    ip: \11.11.11.11
    db:
      name: \my-foo 

  bar-database:~ -> @foo-database `merge` do 
    password: \1234 
    db:
      location: \SF

config.default 
# => {"ip":"192.168.1.5","port":2000,"name":"root","password":"root","db":{"name":"default","location":"LA"}}
config.foo-database  
# => {"ip":"11.11.11.11","port":2000,"name":"root","password":"root","db":{"name":"my-foo","location":"LA"}}
config.bar-database  
# => {"ip":"11.11.11.11","port":2000,"name":"root","password":"1234","db":{"name":"my-foo","location":"SF"}}
```

Comment: That link doesn't actually load the article anymore, which is kind of infuriating.

Comment: I updated the link to point to the archive.org version. My edit is still in peer review. Until then: the link is https://web.archive.org/web/20130213112648/http://blog.101ideas.cz/posts/dry-your-yaml-files.html

Comment: Thanks for the update. I think notifications are a bit problematic in StackOverflow; If I were notified about the first message, I would kindly handle the problem. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Kind of off topic, but I have never heard of livescript before.  That looks absolutely amazing!!!  Is it still used or has it gone the way of coffeescript?

Comment: @Freedom_Ben I do use Livescript in my projects so it's alive for me. See https://gitter.im/gkz/LiveScript?at=6047eb53120cd84f7805a485

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't get the kind of "inheritance" you want to achieve because YAML's "inheritance" is more like a form of "merging hashes".

Expanding out your configuration at the point you use the `*default` alias, you have:

```
foo_database:
  server:
    ip: 192.168.1.5
    port: 2000
  db_name: test
  user: 
    name: root
    password: root
```

If you use hashes with the same keys afterwards, they will *completely overwrite* the hashes declared earlier, leaving you with (excuse the formatting):

```
foo_database:
```

```
  server:
    ip: 192.168.1.5
    port: 2000
  db_name: test
  user: 
   name: root
   password: root
```

```
  server:
    port: 2001
  db_name: foo
  user:
    password: foo_root
```

So, in your case, it would seem that since the config is not *exactly* the same, DRYing up your configuration using anchors and aliases probably isn't the right approach.

More references on this issue below:

- [Rake, YAML and Inherited Build Configuration](http://therightstuff.de/2010/01/30/Rake-YAML-And-Inherited-Build-Configuration.aspx)
- [Merging hashes in yaml conf files](http://atechie.net/2009/07/merging-hashes-in-yaml-conf-files/)

#### Edit

If you really wanted to, I think you could reconfigure your YAML as below to get exactly what you want, but in your case, I would say the extra obfuscation isn't worth it:

```
server_defaults: &server_defaults
  ip: 192.168.1.5
  port: 2000

user_defaults: &user_defaults
  name: root
  password: root

database: &default
  server:
    <<: *server_defaults
  db_name: test
  user: 
    <<: *user_defaults

foo_database:
  <<: *default
  server:
    <<: *server_defaults
    port: 2001
  db_name: foo
  user:
    <<: *user_defaults
    password: foo_root
```

Comment: We are saying more or less the same thing. "Workaround" would work technically but it would not work "practically" because goal of YAML is being human readable. I gave a trivial example. Let's think that we have an object which has about 100 lines and 1 to 6 sub objects. If we need to change 1-2 objects only where one of them is in the deepest node, everywhere would be filled up with anchors. Anchor naming would be more problematic. This is a need. I asked this question because I need to know if I am wrong about approach or not. If not, I will try to implement that kind of inheritance.

Comment: I agree that YAML should be human readable, and hence I do not recommend using the solution in my edit (I only wrote it in case you were very adamant that you wanted results in exactly the way you specified in the question).  Personally, I have only ever used anchors and aliases in YAML to refactor out any repeated code.  I have never aliased repeated code and then overridden *some* of it (like in the edit above), as I think it makes the code harder to read.  If you want to keep things human readable, in your case it will probably mean keeping some of the repetition as well.

Comment: Thank you for your conscientious answers. Yes, you are right, repeated code would be more clear in these conditions. But now I'm introducing a new inheritance operator (no no, don't stop me! :P) as "<<<: *anchor" which means "this object will inherit the object pointed by the anchor and none of the inherited object's object could be deleted, only overridden if explicitly present". Yes. Now I'm logically using this operator (I don't care what the parser says). When I have a free time, I will offer this operator for adding to YAML specification. Thank you Paul :)

Comment: You're welcome, and good luck.  If you end up configuring something interesting, please share it with an edit to your question :-)

Comment: @ceremcem did you ever (partially) complete the `<<<: *anchor` implementation?

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn I started a configuration tool totally scratch called [config-md](https://github.com/aktos-io/config-md) a while ago, but I didn't continue development since I use LiveScript heavily in novadays and it makes handling configuration stuff [very easy](https://gist.github.com/ceremcem/4ca8d774e660c579682839620d8c2da8). In which language would you need to use this?

Comment: The `config-md` is already written in Python. If you have a chance to switch from YAML to another configuration tool, we may make [config-md](https://github.com/aktos-io/aktos-dcs-lib/blob/master/aktos_parser.py) continued...

Answer (score 23):

How about this? Use multiple anchors.

```
database: &default
  server: &server
    ip: 192.168.1.5
    port: 2000
  db_name: test
  user: &user
    name: root
    password: root

foo_database:
  <<: *default
  server:
    << : *server
    port: 2001
  db_name: foo
  user:
    << : *user
    password: foo_root
```

It's just a little extra work, and slightly harder to read than if what you wanted were built into YAML as you suggested (I thought it would work that way too). But overall not bad.

Comment: What I didn't think about is how you said you have 6 levels deep. This then is kind of annoying. Still better I think than not having any benefit from inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

For this sort of problems, I have created a tool: [jq-front](https://github.com/dakusui/jq-front).
By using [yq](https://mikefarah.github.io/yq/) + jq-front, you can achieve it by slightly modifying your input.

**in.yaml:**

```yaml
$local: 
  database_default:
    server:
      ip: 192.168.1.5
      port: 2000
    db_name: test
    user: 
      name: root
      password: root

# database foo differs from default by only its port and user password
foo_database:
  $extends: [ database_default ]
  server:
    port: 2001
  db_name: foo
  user:
    password: foo_root
```

And you can process this file by a following command line.

```
$ yq . -j in.yaml | jq-front  | yq . -y
```

And you will get following output that you wanted.

```
foo_database:
  server:
    ip: 192.168.1.5
    port: 2001
  db_name: foo
  user:
    name: root
    password: foo_root
```

NOTE: <s>jq-front is very slow. On my machine the command took 2.5s, which did not matter to me too much since system configuration can be read once and only the converted file is used by the rest of my program.</s>(Thanks to recent improvements, it is not that much slow, will update the number)

NOTE: If you use docker + bash, it's lot easier to install jq-front by docker. You only need to add following function to your `.bashrc` or a file that is sourced by it.

```
function jq-front() {
  docker run --rm -i \
    -v /:/var/lib/jf \
    -e JF_PATH_BASE="/var/lib/jf" \
    -e JF_PATH="${JF_PATH}" \
    -e JF_DEBUG=${JF_DEBUG:-disabled} \
    -e JF_CWD="$(pwd)" \
    dakusui/jq-front:"${JF_DOCKER_TAG:-latest}" "${@}"
}
```