# How to add variables to docker compose with extension anchor?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, yaml, dockerfile

I am trying to create a `docker-compose` file with anchors but somehow cannot get the variables to work:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

x-test: &default-test
  image: node
  networks: 
    somenet:
      ipv4_address: ${IP_ADDRESS}

services:
  test_cont:
    environment: 
      - IP_ADDRESS=192.168.0.1
    <<: *default-test

networks: 
  somenet:
    ipam: 
      config: 
        - subnet: 192.168.0.0/24
```

With the message when run:

```
WARNING: The IP_ADDRESS variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string
```

How can I set the `IP_ADDRESS` for the services so that I can use the same anchor with different values?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Similar to [More complex inheritance in YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184971/more-complex-inheritance-in-yaml)

Comment: `${IP_ADDRESS}` uses the variable values from the shell environment in which `docker-compose` is run whereas `environment:` adds a variable to the environment of the container

Comment: Is the only thing you're trying to set this way a per-container IP address?  Docker can assign these on its own, and it's usually best to think of these as an implementation detail; I'd probably delete all of the `networks:` blocks you show, and let Compose create a `default` network on its own.